# PHP Sessions and Form input names getting confused

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I am seeing some weird behavior:

I have 2 sessions that I set with some value: `$_SESSION['shippingZip']` and `$_SESSION['shippingOption']`.

Then my code goes through this code to post the input values sent in a form:

```
$shippingOption = $_POST['shippingOption'];
Print_r ($_SESSION);
$shippingZip = $_POST['shippingZip'];
```

Those POSTs are coming empty in this pass. However, the Print shows my session $_SESSION['shippingOption'] empty, when it should show the string that had previously been assigned to it.
-------------------------- POSTING FULL PROOF
Sessions are loaded with some data:

```
$_SESSION['shippingOption'] = $shippingOption;
$_SESSION['shippingZip']= $shippingZip;
```

Then:

```
Print_r ($_SESSION);
$shippingOption = $_POST['shippingOption'];
Print_r ($_SESSION);
$shippingZip = $_POST['shippingZip'];
Print_r ($_SESSION);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [itemAdded] => 1 [Payment_Amount] => 46.52 [cart] => Array ( [4] => Array ( [itemId] => 4 [qty] => 1 ) ) [shippingOption] => FIRST CLASS [shippingZip] => 10025 [shippingPrice] => 1.52 ) 
Array ( [itemAdded] => 1 [Payment_Amount] => 46.52 [cart] => Array ( [4] => Array ( [itemId] => 4 [qty] => 1 ) ) [shippingOption] => [shippingZip] => 10025 [shippingPrice] => 1.52 ) 
Array ( [itemAdded] => 1 [Payment_Amount] => 46.52 [cart] => Array ( [4] => Array ( [itemId] => 4 [qty] => 1 ) ) [shippingOption] => [shippingZip] => [shippingPrice] => 1.52
```

You can clearly see how after each POST, the SESSION with the same name loses its value. It's totally crazy!!!

Comment: What/where are you setting the sessions? and with what data?

Comment: There's no relationship between `$_SESSION` and `$_POST`. Could you show what you're seeing, it's really hard to understand from your description.

Comment: In particular, if `print_r($_SESSION)` shows it as empty, why do you think the session is inheriting the POST values?

Comment: When I put the Print before the $shippingOption, $_SESSION['shippingOption'] shows the expected string value. When I put it right after (as in the example) the session $_SESSION['shippingOption'] shows empty

Comment: Have you by any chance been using the long-deprecated [session_register()](http://php.net/session_register) function? That would explain an ordinary (but global) variable over-writing a session variable.

Comment: Not using session_register()

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` does not directly populate `$_SESSION`. You need to assign the values to the session

i.e.

```
$_SESSION['shippingOption'] = $_POST['shippingOption'];
```

EDIT

After you posted more code, it looks like you are not defining `$shippingOption;` before setting it `$_SESSION['shippingOption'] = $shippingOption;`

Make sure the order goes like this:

```
$shippingOption = $_POST['shippingOption'];
$_SESSION['shippingOption'] = $shippingOption;
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I assigned values to those sessions earlier in my code

Comment: Post that code. I'd bet 1. you're not setting them correctly, or 2. Your form isn't passing the `$_POST` values correctly. Either way, you'll need to post more code.

Comment: Updated the post. And added the output to show how the Sessions loose their values sequentially

Comment: Are you defining `$shippingOption;` before or after adding it to `$_SESSION['shippingOption'] = $shippingOption;`?

Comment: Before. Otherwise the Print would never show values for those Sessions... right?